# How to send files to other iPhones via Bluetooth

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, bluetooth

I'm doing a little app to allow users to edit and share text fast on the iPhone.

So I know a little of Bluetooth programing for iPhone, but I'm not able to do what I want to do:

- The text of the app is saved in NSUserDefaults. I want to send this to another iOS device by the key: "Text1", "Text2" or "Text3"( I know that I have to convert the text that will be in a string to NSData, and tren I would like to have it in a NSMutableDictionary with its key)
- I also want to be looking for new iOS devices arround all the time.

Please help me because I don't know how I can do it and it's so hard to find tutorials of iPhone Bluetooth programming, thank you!

Comment: I am also in need of a library to share file/text to another iOS Device. do you have any library to refer or share any example code.Thanks..!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use GameKit, there are many tutorials.

Use this to find other devices:

```
GKPeerPickerController *picker = [[GKPeerPickerController alloc] init];
picker.delegate = self;
picker.connectionTypesMask = GKPeerPickerConnectionTypeNearby;
[picker show];
```

Comment: I have solved by myself using GameKit my first question; but the second one, the automatic Bluetooth® connection to other iDevices, isn't, and I have no idea how to do it. Do you?

Comment: GameKit has a method for that as well. Check the delegate methods for connections and discovable

Comment: Can your answer be more explainative?

Comment: I've updated my answer, be sure to include the appropriate delegates in the header file